# ffmpeg: unable to read file from Azure server (works locally & from AWS)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webserver, streaming, azure

I need to be able to read a video with ffmpeg and to extract its frames to JPG pictures. I'm using this command:

```
./ffmpeg -y -r 25 -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M -i http://webserver/video.mp4 -q:v 5 /destination/image_%03d.jpg
```

It works fine if the video is stored on the device or on an Amazon AWS server, but it doesn't if it is stored on a Windows Azure server. If the video is encoded in webm, it works everywhere, but I need it to be in mp4 for some reasons.

Here is the ffmpeg output:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf70d7000] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf70d7000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 960x540, 1236 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
http://server/video.mp4: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://server/video.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
Duration: 00:00:01.44, bitrate: 1241 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 960x540, 1236 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
[buffer @ 0xf703a000] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0xf703a000] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf70dd190] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

Any idea of what's wrong? Could Azure server break something? The file isn't corrupted, if I download it and play it locally it works.

Comment: Since when you download it play it locally it works, why not just download the input with `curl` or `wget` or whatever then use the local copy as the input?

Comment: in order to start displaying the JPG picture asap. Downloading the file fixes the problem but it is too slow.

Comment: Hi, what is your Azure VM size?

Comment: I have no idea, the Azure server is owned and managed by our customer. Why are you asking this? Video size are usually less than 10MB.

Comment: I don't think Azure will limit this.

Comment: I don't think either, but why did you ask about the VM size?

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain that the files on Azure and AWS are exactly the same? As in "the checksums match" same? Because the fact that webm versions work fine makes me think that the file stored on Azure has its index stored at the end of the file, while for streaming and doing other operations to the file before finishing the download you'd need it to be at the beginning.

There might be something else wrong with the Azure input file, perhaps it's corrupted? There's also [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659267/ffmpeg-10-04-could-not-find-codec-parameters#11659459) that recommends setting `-probesize` to 100 and `-analyzeduration` to 10M (the latter of which you seem to have).

Comment: Yeah the files are exactly the same, size is the same, checksum is the same, and downloading and reading locally works :/ . I also tried to set the probesize and analyzeduration, didn't change anything.